Is there a way to get the name of a variable as a string value in Delphi?
Let's say I have the following variables:
var
  FirstName: String;
  LastName: String;
  Age: Integer;

I want a function where I can pass in the variable and then get back the name of the variable as a string. So let's assume this is possible and the function's name is GetVariableName, then if I pass FirstName to it like this: GetVariableName(FirstName), it would return "FirstName" as a string. Same for LastName and Age also.
Is this possible? If yes, then how?
Ideally I'd like for it to work with any data type as well, but it's not necessary.

Edit: This question doesn't help me and isn't a duplicate. I don't care whether it's using RTTI or not whereas that question is specifically using RTTI and then the answer says it's not possible using RTTI.

And what should be returned if you hand over Rec.File.Name? With instances of a class you could get its name with .ClassName.

@AmigoJack I'm personally just interested in normal variables like in the example. I don't care about classes and class names.

It is a duplicate, because getting variable names is not possible. Only types (using RTTI) and classes. My Question was intended to make you think about how many cases would lead to ambiguity, not what you're "just interested in".

Of course this question is not a duplicate of the linked question; which is how to get variable names using RTTI. This question is not about limiting ourselves to RTTI. @AmigoJack "What should be returned if you hand over Rec.File.Name?" Answer: 'Name' (source)

In any case, the answer is that this isn't possible. Delphi is a compiled language and the final EXE file doesn't even contain the identifiers from the source code. This would, however, be possible with a magic compiler function, that simply replaces GetVariableName(SomeVariable) with 'SomeVariable'. Until such a magic function is added by Embarcadero, you'll need to write 'SomeVariable' yourself. But of course this will not be compatible with sync edit mode and things like that.

"I don't care whether it's using RTTI or not whereas that question is specifically using RTTI and then the answer says it's not possible using RTTI." It is duplicate because it is purpose of RTTI to carry information like the one you are asking for. So if you cannot retrieve particular information through RTTI, you will not be able to get it because it simply does not exist.

@DalijaPrasnikar: Well, to be fair to the OP, a magic compiler function like GetVariableName could act like a compile-time "macro", and if so, it should not be classified as RTTI.

@AndreasRejbrand Yes, but such function does not exist. In this case duplicate directs people to RTTI solution which might be applicable in their case.

@DalijaPrasnikar: "...if you cannot retrieve particular information through RTTI, you will not be able to get it because it simply does not exist."  Is using .ClassName a case of using RTTI?  I don't think so, which shows that RTTI is not the only way to get the name of something.

@PhilipJ.Rayment Maybe not in Delphi terms, but in general .Classname is considered RTTI. Think of old versions that didn't had a distinctive RTTI unit.

@PhilipJ.Rayment .ClassName is still part of the RTTI. Even though RTTI got extended at some point, RTTI was a base for Delphi component streaming system from the beginning. See System.TypInfo

"In any case, the answer is that this isn't possible.". I know. But phrase that as an answer


Is this possible?

No, it is not possible, at least not with a function call at runtime. Variable names simply do not exist at runtime, they are translated into memory addresses by the compilation process.
What you are asking for would require pre-processing your source code with a custom script before compiling, as there is no compile-time intrinsic available that does what you want.
